# Compile Time Error - Corrupt XIB/NIB in XCode 4.1, iOS 4

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, xcode4, corruption

Could anyone suggest what this error might be caused by and suggest any possible solution? This is a *compile time* error and doesn't seem to have anything to do with code as the file in question is a xib.

[image: MessageBox]
[image: Error message]

The series of events which *seems* to lead to this error was:

- Write project
- Save project to USB drive
- Open project at different location

This suggests to me that the problem is internal to XCode or there was corruption when copying to the USB but I haven't been able to verify either of those options. If anyone could shed some light on this, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to **re-create** the nib as no attempt to rescue the current one or replace it with an old copy was successful.

If anyone has has the same problem and did find a way to solve it without re-creating the nib, I'd still like to know please!